# how do I select an element from a list based on a child value of it's grandparent

Tags: javascript, xpath

1. this is the object I'm trying to select: $x('//div[contains(@class,"react-select__value-container")]')
   ** There are 10 of these **
2. this is the grandparent object: $x('//div[@class="chart-option"]/label[.="Layer"]/..') ** There is only one of these **
3. the parent is a simple //div[contains(@class, "react-select")]

So the code looks like this:

```
<div class="chart-option">
   <label>Layer</label>
   <div class="react-select css-2b097c-container">
      <div class="react-select__value-container css-1hwfws3">
```

So I need the "value-container" who's grandparent has the child /label[.="Layer"]

But I can't for the life of me get the ordering right and relative syntax to get it. Is there a good tutorial for this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where are the closing `<div>` tags located in your sample code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this xpath:

```
//div[@class="chart-option"][label="Layer"]/div[div[contains(@class,"react-select__value-container")]]
```

## Explanation

```
//div[@class="chart-option"][label="Layer"]
```

Looking anywhere in the document, select `div` tags such that (1) the `class` is `chart-option` and (2) there is a child tag called `label` with the value `Layer`.

```
/div[div[contains(@class,"react-select__value-container")]]
```

Looking at each node in the previous result set above, select all child `div` tags such that *that child* `div` tag itself has a `div` tag that matches the class pattern you have given. (In other words, match based on the grandchild's `class`, but ultimately select the child `div` tag.)

## Test Cases

Here are some more test cases that I used. You can test using an online xpath testing tool.

```
<div>
    <div class="chart-option">
        <label>nope</label>
        <div class="react-select css-WRONG-container">
            <div class="react-select__value-container css-WRONG">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="chart-option">
        <label>Layer</label>
        <div class="react-select css-CORRECT-container">
            <div class="react-select__value-container css-CORRECT">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="chart-option">
        <label>Not Layer</label>
        <div class="react-select css-WRONG-container">
            <div class="react-select__value-container css-WRONG">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <label>Layer</label>
    <div class="react-select css-WRONG-container">
        <div class="react-select__value-container css-WRONG">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="chart-option">
        <label>Layer</label>
        <div class="WRONG-AGAIN">
            <div class="WRONG-AGAIN">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Best explanation I've seen of xpath selection by hierarchy yet!  I would +10 this if I could. Thanks